# How do I add a conditional column to a union query in MS SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In MS SQL is there a way I can add a conditional column to a union query like the one below based on the value of the first column?

basically im trying to add the bin value as a fourth column if the part value is like ('%XX') or have it display 0, so far I have only been able to add another column which mirrors the MAX(part_bins.bin) column if the code doesn't meet the like.

```
SELECT part_bins.part AS part,
       SUM(part_bins.free_stock) AS FREE_STOCK,
       MAX(PART_BINS.BIN) AS Bin
FROM part_bins
LEFT OUTER JOIN part ON part_bins.part = part.part
WHERE (part_bins.free_stock > 0)
GROUP BY part_bins.part
UNION
SELECT part.master_part AS part,
       SUM(part_bins.free_stock) AS FREE_STOCK,
       MAX(PART_BINS.BIN) AS Bin
FROM part_bins
LEFT OUTER JOIN part ON part_bins.part = part.part
WHERE (part_bins.free_stock > 0)
GROUP BY part.master_part
```

Comment: You can add even in this query, only you have to add the column in both queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` statement and you have to add it in both queries to add the fourth column like;

```
--4th Column for both queries, if bin_value is a numeric type
case when part_value like '%XX' then bin_value 
       else 0 end as fourth_column

--4th Column for both queries, if bin_value is a string type
case when part_value like '%XX' then bin_value 
       else '0' end as fourth_column
```